# currentText() doesn't collect data from field

Tags: python, pyqt5

My program is currently divided into 2 files: one with GUI and second with code. In GUI, there's button I want to use to collect the data from text fields and put them into variables:

```
self.dodaj.clicked.connect(Dodaj_Ksiazke.pobierz_dane)
```

It's supposed to call the function "pobierz_dane". Inside the code there is class "Main" where above function is defined:

```
def pobierz_dane(self):
    print("Pobieranie danych z formularza do zmiennych")
    print(self.ui.isbn.currentText())
    isbn = self.ui.isbn.currentText()
    print(isbn)
```

As you can see I tried various ways to confirm it's working. When I start the program and click the button the first print gets displayed but not the 2nd or 3rd one, this is where program crashes with error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Text field I'm trying to get the text from is defined like this:

```
    self.isbn = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.isbn.setObjectName("isbn")
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.isbn, 1, 2, 1, 1)
```

This is the beginning of GUI deifnition:

```
class Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dodaj_Ksiazke):
```

And Main class from file with code:

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke):
    def __init__(self):
       QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
       self.ui= Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Since the first print is working I guess the button correctly calls the function. But I can't nail why it's not working for the text field as I don't get any errors when running the program.

Comment: provide a [mcve], 
and do not run it in an IDE, use the terminal or CMD, there you will get the error message.

Comment: I didn't know that IDE is not providing all information. This is the result of running the program via CMD:
`C:\Users\jakub\PycharmProjects\biblioteka>py main.py
Pobieranie danych z formularza do zmiennych
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 124, in pobierz_dane
    print(self.ui.isbn.currentText())
AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'currentText'`

Looks like the 'currentText' is the problem. Thank you for this.

Comment: I had to replace 'currentText' with 'displayText' and now all works - variable gets displayed and program doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: use setCurrenText()

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by switching from currentText() to displayText() as there is no attribute 'currentText' in QLineEdit.

```
isbn = self.ui.isbn.displayText()
```

Text is taken from text field stored correctly in variable, displayed by print() and program doesn't crash.